# Бывает ли revolution slider не плагином?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wp-plugin

Добрый день, скажите revolution slider бывает в отдельной сборке, не для wp joomla итд, что бы можно было его заюзать отдельно для html макета.

Comment: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ вот попробуй поюзать или легонький https://github.com/pawelgrzybek/siema

Comment: а [это](https://codecanyon.net/item/slider-revolution-responsive-jquery-plugin/2580848) разве не то, что нужно?

Comment: юзал я это все уже, не-то это все.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по [сайту разработчика](https://revolution.themepunch.com), не бывает. А если и существует где-то  нечто подобное, то это уже не revolution slider.